# Trouble with ASP.NET HttpWebRequest POST to a site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, post, httpwebrequest

ASP.NET 4.0

Need some help with this vexing HTTP POST problem - I have looked at other posts on Stackoverflow but to no avail.

**Problem summary**: It's a classic case - I want to login to an external site which takes 2 parameters to login, and I need to use a POST to do it

**What happens**: I do a POST and the HTTP response that comes back is essentially the same page that I posted to in the first place (i.e. it hasn't really logged in)

**Things I've done:** I have fiddler (protocol analyzer) running, and I have comparisons of my POST and a working POST (from another desktop app), but I can't seem to reproduce the same behavior

**[edit 1]:** It appears to be a cookie issue (the code below is now outdated, I've made modifications), I have managed to set all the parameters correctly. Problem not resolved as of this edit.

Below is my code and the I have also reproduced the comparison headers

```
 private static void doPost(string URL)
    {
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        myRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.126 Safari/533.4";
        CookieContainer cCookie = new CookieContainer();
        myRequest.CookieContainer = cCookie;
        myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        myRequest.Accept = "application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";            

        string postData = "param1=somevalue&param2=someothervalue";
        ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] bData = ascii.GetBytes(postData);

        myRequest.Method = "POST";
        myRequest.ContentLength = bData.Length;

        Stream oStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
        oStream.Write(bData, 0, bData.Length);

        string oResp = string.Empty;

        using (var resp = myRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    oResp = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(oResp);        
    }
```

I do get a HTTP 1.1 OK but the response text is the same page I posted to - i.e. the login page, which suggests that my post did not actually succeed.

Now here are the comparison POSTS

a) FROM MY APPLICATION (DOESN'T WORK)

`POST https://[someURL] HTTP/1.1

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.126 Safari/533.4

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,/;q=0.5

Host: xxxx.com

Content-Length: 64

Expect: 100-continue

Connection: Keep-Alive



param1=value1&param2=value2`

b) FROM THE POST THAT WORKS (A DIFFERENT DESKTOP APP DOING THE SAME THING)

`POST https:[someURL] HTTP/1.1 

Accept: image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, application/x-shockwave-flash, / 

Referer: [someURL] 

Accept-Language: en-US 

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 

User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) 

Host: xxxxxx.com

Content-Length: 2815

Connection: Keep-Alive

Cache-Control: no-cache

Cookie: ccccc1=10; blahblah=pppqqqrrr; ASP.NET_SessionId=jp4mjg45z34si545om3nouew`

SomeField=False&__VIEWSTATE1=1H4sIAA3mnn8A%2F31WTbequfx[TRUNCATED]jF%2FLkgCgAA&__VIEWSTATE0=3&__VIEWSTATE=&__VIEWSTATE=&param1=value1&param2=value2&x=0&y=0

As you can see, the second POST is much bigger - the key differences are

1. There are some cookies, whereas mine don't show any
2. The POST header shows these additional fields (SomeField, VIEWSTATE1, etc.) - how I do access them to do the same?

Do I first need to do a GET, parse the body, extract these VIEWSTATE1--3 & SomeField, and then reset it in the post body data bytes? I could try many things but it would be much appreciated if someone tells me if I'm way off track or am doing something fundamentally wrong...

I plan to use the Html Agility pack to parse the HTML

thanks a bunch,
g

Comment: I am treating this as closed as I've gone well beyond the scope of the question. it appears my problem has nothing to do with cookies either, but something else! (don't know what yet..the struggle continues).

Comment: See my new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484558/vexed-post-returns-a-302-found-object-moved-error-in-httpwebrequest for the continuing story

Comment: See my post in the above comment for the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably that you need to supply a session cookie with your login request.

What you need to do is first make a normal GET request to the login page. Add all response cookies to your CookieContainer and then use the same CookieContainer when making the actual POST login request.

Also, try and mimic the real request as much as possible. Use the same Referer value etc.

Have a look at this question [logged in to PureVolume.com programatically !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359762/logged-in-to-purevolume-com-programatically/3359934#3359934)

Edit: Depending on how the site you are trying to login to is designed you might need to parse and supply the ViewState data as you suggested. But since an initial GET request most likely already is required this shouldn't be to hard to do.

Comment: Jesper - thanks a bunch. Will try it. I have managed to parse the viewstate and other input values from GET and have been able to reproduce the POST - the only thing missing now are the cookies! I will do what you suggested and post back on what I have. (After I fixed the POST input values, I get an error response page - at least a different response! I suspect it's because of cookies)

Comment: Jesper - I have more to report. My GET and POST are consistent with IE. With the browser I can login, but with my POST I get a 302 with a error page. There is just one difference - IE does this:
- GET
- POST (success), and this post has cookies (3 pieces of which one is ASP session ID)

mine:
-GET
-POST (failure), has cookies, but only 1 (which is a ASP session id), the other cookies don't show up.

Everything else is fine - and I did look at the link you added and did exactly that for cookies, but no luck! What am I missing? This is driving me nuts!

Comment: Do you see the missing cookies in the response from your initial GET request in Fiddler?

Comment: No I don't - that's the annoying thing. But then when I tried a new IE session, the first GET shows no cookies, but the subsequent POST shows all of them (in fiddler). For me, the GET gets me the ASP.NET_SessionId= cookie and nothing else. So when I POST, that's the only cookie I have and the page seems to reject it. My GET is pretty much exact as the browser GETs, the only difference is mine is a desktop console app. What am I missing?

Comment: If the cookies isn't returned by the response then they are set by a client side script, ie JavaScript. Check the page source and look for any javascript setting cookies.

Comment: Jesper, it appears so! There's a JS script that's getting included at end of the page and it has a whole lot of cookie related code. Sorry to be thick - I've never ever done anything like this before, but is there a way I can read it? I mean I'm just doing a GET so presumably the JS isn't getting extracted etc. The other desktop app apparently is pulling this off in some way...I'm a bit lost now. Will keep researching, thanks.